# Python Selenuim Crashes

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

When I run my code it crashes please help and this was made late at night so I may have missed something obv. Instead of launching chrome driver like my other programs Ive made it runs actual chrome. is there a fix?

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
import time

# change 'ip:port' with your proxy's ip and port
proxy_ip_port = '95.217.168.246:8888'

proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy.http_proxy = proxy_ip_port
proxy.ssl_proxy = proxy_ip_port

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

# replace 'your_absolute_path' with your chrome binary absolute path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Python dsicord bot\chromedriver',
                          desired_capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get('http://whatismyipaddress.com')

time.sleep(8)```






**Error:** 

```DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57598/devtools/browser/120e371a-b935-4d04-9057-de3f728ce8b0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\andre\Desktop\Python dsicord bot\sys.py", line 17, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Python dsicord bot\chromedriver',
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
Current browser version is 92.0.4515.159 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created:This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
```

is basically you do not have compatible version of browser and browser driver.

### as of 29th-Aug-2021

```
Latest stable release: ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107
```

and Google chrome browser version is `Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Download [link](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/) for chromedriver, try to get 92.0, and that should help you past this issue.

Comment: I know you have, but it is 93 which is a beat version not stable version, you should use 92 and see if that helps, always I have given you a link above, you can download from there. Also, there's a auto installer too, let me know if you wanna that feature in your bot as well.